# ICMP requests are blocked

Tags: ufw

I connected a Kubuntu 14.04 machine to a Debian 7.0 with a cross cable. The problem: ping is one-directional. Kubuntu machine can see Debian, but Debian can't ping Kubuntu.

Notes:

- Firewall is disabled on both machines:

  `$ sudo ufw status
  $ Status: inactive`

**Update**

`ifconfig` results:

ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 
          inet addr:192.168.1.10  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f24d:a2ff:fe90:ec31/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:347 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:495 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:50712 (50.7 KB)  TX bytes:57402 (57.4 KB)
```

`ping` from Kubuntu (192.168.1.10) to itself:

```
ping 192.168.1.10
PING 192.168.1.10 (192.168.1.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.1.10 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 9000ms
```

`route -n` returns:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

Comment: What IP's and netmasks are given? And can you ping the machine itself?

Comment: @chaos I can't ping the machine itself! See the update

Comment: Do a ping to 127.0.0.1 instead of using the IP of 192.168.1.10

Comment: ping 127.0.0.1 is successful

Comment: Is there another computer on the network that accidentally has 192.168.1.10?

Comment: Can your provide the information of `route -n`?

Comment: @Jos No. I'm connecting two machines directly (using a cross-cable) there is no router, switch between.

Comment: @chaos See update please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `wlan0` interface is in the same subnet.
You have 2 options:

1. Change the IPs of both machines (debian & kubuntu) that they are in another subnet, for example `192.168.2.10`.
2. Disable the wireless interface or change it's IP that it's in another subnet.

Comment: Haha! Now it works.